# warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I have a function that use a string `x` , and at the end of that function I return `&x[0]`
i have this warning `warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]`.
How can I fix this ? Thank you

Comment: Don't return the address of something that will cease to exist when the function ends. It's hard to say more with such minimal information provided.

Comment: You need to show what exactly your function does so we can think up a possible solution to the problem. As for the reason of the warning, it's pretty self-explanatory: `x` will be destroyed when the function ends so the address is invalid.